# How can i compile boost::spirit for unsigned char type?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

boost::spirit asserts at
    boost::spirit::char_class::ascii::isalnum()

when passing ascci characters > 127.

I changed all my private variables from std::string to a

```
typedef std::basic_string<unsigned char, std::char_traits<unsigned char>, std::allocator<unsigned char> >
 u_string;
```

but still boost uses std:.string internally. What do i have to do ?

Comment: Post your code, and tell us exactly what you see it doing when you execute it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is quite simple:

instead of

```
using namespace boost::spirit::ascii;
```

i now use

```
using namespace boost::spirit::iso8859_1;
```

This recognizes all charcters in the iso8859 character set.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is of course that there are no ASCII characters above 127. The interpretation of byte=8 bit is more recent than that.

If you're using ISO8859-1 or UTF-8 as a character encoding, you should configure your compiler correctly. This option micht be called " default char unsigned" or something like that, to reflect the fact that ISO-8859 does use character values above 127.